Tag request: plantcv
If possible, I would like to request a plantcv tag for Stack Overflow. PlantCV is an open-source Python library for plant phenotyping with image analysis. It is currently developed by computational biologists at the Donald Danforth Plant Sciences Center, a non-profit research institute.
The library has 5,000 installs per month on PyPI, 655 stars, and 60 contributors on GitHub. It is a bona fide open-source, open-science project aimed at biologists who do not necessarily have a computer science background. One of the goals of the software is to lower the barrier to entry for computer-vision for botanists. The motivation behind wanting a Stack Overflow tag is to make questions about the package as accessible and discoverable as possible.
Could someone please either create this tag or direct me on how to request one?
I apologize if this is not the correct way to request a new tag. I searched for information on requesting a new tag, and this 13-year-old question was all I could find. It mentioned that only someone with 1500 reputation points can create a new tag, but I couldn't find information on requesting a new tag.
Also, if possible please create plantcvand not plantcv.py - the library has a growing number of user who use R to analyze the data generated by the library.
Here are some of the existing untagged question and answers about the library:-

object in foreground with ambient light and shadows

Here is my draft for the tag Wiki:-
Wiki tag: For questions about the image analysis Python library PlantCV. Use additional tags such as [python], [opencv], [scikit-image], etc. if you are using other packages in conjunction with PlantCV.When asking a PlantCV question, you should:

Include relevant code.
Include the OS: [e.g. Linux, macOS, Windows]
Include the Environment [e.g. conda, virtualenv, pip, docker, etc.]
Include the PlantCV version  [e.g. 4.5.0]

About PlantCV
PlantCV is an open-source, Python-based image analysis software package, specifically for plant science (though it can be used for any application).  PlantCV was launched in 2014 from the Donald Danforth Plant Science Center. It contains user-friendly, modular functions for building flexible image analysis workflows.
PlantCV can be used to build basic image processing workflows (segmentation, color correction, etc.) and analyze size, shape, and color of objects of interest. PlantCV also supports workflow parallelization.
PlantCV supports Windows, Linux, and macOS systems.
Homepage: https://plantcv.org/
Documentation: https://plantcv.readthedocs.io/
Tutorials: https://plantcv.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/

You've seen this https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges and this https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags ?

Hi @AugustoVasques - I apologize for not being clear. What I meant to really do was request a new tag from someone who can make it because I can't do so myself. The extra text was to explain that I tried to look for a formal way to request tags but couldn't find one. Cheers!

We can't just create a tag, @Sudoh, there needs to be a question which is relevant for said tag. If there are no such questions, then the reason the tags doesn't exist is because there are no questions.

Hi @ThomA a bit sloppy on my part but I should have listed existing untagged questions/answers. I have added some new ones I was able to find. Is this what you need?

"I apologize if this is not the correct way to request a new tag. I searched for information on requesting a new tag,..." I believe the current guidance is here: When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?

@Sudoh I've removed the 3 answers you'd linked since the question they were on didn't seem to be about PlantCV. If we add a certain tag to a question the tag should directly be relevant to the question (rather than being used because an answer used the library relevant to the tag)

Created. Please submit wiki for community approval:  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/plantcv/info

Hi @TheMaster I have updated the post a draft of the wiki. Is this what you were looking for? I followed your link but the webpage didn't have a way for me to submit the wiki.

@Sudoh I think they wanted you to suggest a tag wiki (You should be able to see a "Create tag info" button on the page they linked). Although given you posted the content here please note that tag wikis and excerpts should not simply be copy pasted. Looking at your suggested excerpt you've entirely copied it from their repos readme

Mini-feedback: You use 2 different spellings for the product: Plant-CV + PlantCV, be consistent, and PlantCV seems to be the correct spelling. // Both Excerpt + Wiki are just copied from the GitHub Rep and feel very "Marketing Propaganda"... // Excerpt should mention Tag Usage, => to also include the [python] or [r] Programming Language. // Wiki: The last 2 paragraphs are really not needed on 'SO', we don't care about calling for volunteers to participate in the Project... // + Typo in Wiki: "accessible to biologist" (=> "biologists" (Plural)).

Hi @AbdulAzizBarkat The "Create tag info" button does not seem accessible to me, perhaps a account reputation threshold issue? Yes - the excerpt was copied from the package's README. I thought, with attribution, the package authors'/maintainers' own words would make for the best tag except and description. They have worked on the package documentation for years. I apologize for the hassle.

We have plagiarism rules. We can't use their description without attribution. Furthermore, excerpt is not just a description. It is a set of guidance regarding when to use this tag and when not to use tag. See eg: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

@TheMaster Got it, apologies for the attribution error. I have added a new draft for the tag wiki.

@Sudoh As written in tag wiki documentation, All registered users can submit edits for tag wikis. I believe your should be able to add wiki. If you're unable to find  the "Create tag wiki" button, could you add a screenshot here or ask a new support question here with your full page screenshot?

@TheMaster This took a bit of searching around but the edit tag button shows up when I hover my mouse over the tag itself. That I need to hover over the tag for the button to show up was unclear to me when I made my comment but have submitted a wiki now.
